# Fetch data in JSON format to display on a lightning bar graph

Tags: lightning, json

I have setup a Apex controller to get aggregate values from a custom object. I want to display those data on a lightning bar graph (Total vs Year)

My Apex Aura controller

```
public class EnrolmentsPerYearAuraController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<EnrolmentQueryResults> getEnrolmentsPerYear(){
        List<AggregateResult> agrResults = [SELECT CALENDAR_YEAR(Start_date__c) startYear,
                                            Count(Id) total
                                            FROM Training_Agreement__c
                                            WHERE CALENDAR_YEAR(Start_date__c) >2011 AND
                                            (Status__c != NULL OR Non_TEC_Funded_Status__c != NULL) AND
                                            (Company__c = 'CityFitness HO'OR parent_Company_for_community__c ='CityFitness HO')
                                             GROUP BY CALENDAR_YEAR(Start_date__c)
                                             ORDER By CALENDAR_YEAR(Start_date__c)];

         List<EnrolmentQueryResults> aqResults = new List<EnrolmentQueryResults>(); 
        for (AggregateResult ar: agrResults){
                aqResults.add(new EnrolmentQueryResults(ar));  
            }
        return aqResults;
    }
}

public class EnrolmentQueryResults {
    @AuraEnabled
    public String Year {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public Decimal Total {get; set;}

    //constructor
    public EnrolmentQueryResults(AggregateResult ar){
        Year = (String)ar.get('StartYear');
        Total = (Decimal)ar.get('total');
    }
}
```

I want Total values and Year as a bar graph according to this link
https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingdetail?listingid=a0N30000000pvQzEAI

Thanks in advance 
jay

Comment: There isn't much of a question written here. Where are you stuck? How can we assist? What have you tried?

Comment: Can you see the Apex controller EnrolmentsPerYearAuraController class to extract data. Then EnrolmentQueryResults class and constructor at the bottom half. What I want return data 'Total' and 'Year' to be displayed as a bar graph on a lightning page. I know how to setup the page. using the link https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingdetail?listingid=a0N30000000pvQzEAI The only proble is how to get the data in JSON format which required as per the link, thanks